# Devise not redirecting to specified page after User sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

**Problem**: I am using the `after_sign_up_path_for(resource)` method provided by Devise but I cannot seem to get the User redirected to the specified page after they sign up. Currently I receive a `Template Missing` error with the url being `www.localhost:3000/users`. Ideally, I would like to have the User redirected to `www.localhost:3000/subscribers/new`

**registrations_controller.rb**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    @user = User.new(sign_up_params)
    @domain = @user.email.split('@').last
    @company = Company.find_by_domain(@domain)
    @user.company_id = @company.id

    if @user.save
      after_sign_up_path_for(@user)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def sign_up_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :participation_code, :company_id)
    end


  protected

    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      "/subscribers/new"
    end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
...
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }
...
```

**Error Log I Get**:

```
Template is Missing

Missing template registrations/create, devise/registrations/create,    
devise/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=  
[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby,   
:coffee, :arb, :haml, :jbuilder]}.
```

**UPDATE:** I have tried moving the `after_sign_up_path_for(resource)` to the `ApplicationController` but still got the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very interesting. I simply changed

```
def create
...
end
```

to...

```
def update
...
end
```

Now everything works perfectly and my `after_sign_up_path_for(resource)` method is recognized.

Answer (score -1):

Add below method in your application controller

## Devise: Where to redirect users once they have logged in

```
 def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
   "http://www.google.com" # <- Path you want to redirect the user to.
 end
```

Comment: I have tried that already and got the same result. I updated my post to reflect this.

Comment: You got template missing error or its not redirect to path? can you paste log in your question?

Comment: One thing can you check first remove custom redirection and check its work or not? If its not work then you need to fix that.

Comment: You need to generate devise views.
     rails generate devise:views
also review below link:
    https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it worth to put redirect_method in after_action : create callback?

Answer (score -1):

you dont need to create controller you can redirect user to specific path by defining

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
   your_path
 end
```

remember use after_sign_in_path_for not after_sign_up_path_for